# How can you reliably melee?

Tags: team-fortress-arcade

It appears that melee attack is pressing attack plus jump at the same time, but that more often than not triggers a secondary jump-attack.

Am I doing it wrong? How are you supposed to melee?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you're not doing it right.  It has to be at the same time.  It sounds like you're actually hitting jump first, then attack.

It might not be your fault though.  It could be your keyboard and it doesn't support pressing as much multiple keys simultaneously.  Try playing as a different player using different keys.  I would suggest player 2 (for the arrow keys) or player 4 (for the numpad).  In my experience, pressing multiple keys with those are usually not a problem on any keyboard, and say... four keys at most (maybe five) per player isn't too much of a burden.

If you have a joystick, you could use a program like [JoyToKey](http://www-en.jtksoft.net/) (now shareware) to map the keyboard keys to your joystick and use that instead.  Older versions ([v3.74](http://www.electracode.com/4/joy2key/JoyToKey%20English%20Version.htm)) are still freeware AFAIK and are usually more than adequate, I've used this one all the time using Windows XP.  Not sure about the support on more current operating systems.

Comment: Good point about the number of keys that I can truly press together at the same time; I hadn't thought of that possibly getting in the way.